# post_content return zero!

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am new to WordPress
I made a function as a subscription form.
when I want to check it on another function I use

```
 global $post;
    if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'up-vip')) {....}
```

I don't know why post_content retun zero : ["post_content"]=> string(0)
I need it to return  ["post_content"]=> string(8) "[up-vip]"

if you need more detail please let me know
"

```
<?php

function upgrade()
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form id="form" method="post">
        <div class="order-table">
            <ul class="pay">
                <li><label for="plan"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Plans</label></li>
                <li>
                    <select class="ddl" id="plan" name="plan">
                        <option value="1month">choose a plan</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li><label for="gate"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Select the Bank</label></li>
                <li>
                    <select class="ddl" id="gate" name="gate">
                        <option value="elbank">EL Bank</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="button-buy"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>BUY</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('up-vip', 'upgrade');
?>
```

Comment: where is `$post` coming from? Can you tell us where the code snippet with `has_shortcode` is located and when it runs? It would be helpful to see the previous 20 lines of code for context

Comment: @TomJNowell  thanks for your reply. It comes from global $post;
It's a form for buying a subscription. after a user clicks on the buy button. in our plugin we check it with has_shortcode
could you please click on the buy button? you can see var dump log
https://tmcd.ir//HbPV

Comment: are you sure that `$post` has the actual value? If there is no current post set then `$post` may not have a value yet, or have the value you thought it would. Ignore `has_shortcode` and check that `$post` is the post you expected it to be with a valid ID and the title you're expecting. Also _where_ `global $post` is located is important. Be sure to include the previous 20 lines of code _unmodified_, hiding details even to try and be helpful hurts your question and conceals the problem